# PHP Variables to display in Acending Table

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know whether any syntax is required to complete what I want to achieve.
I know this may be poor coding practice but I have no time to correct this solution at the moment.

I need the AMOUNT to list in Ascending order and NAME to follow the corresponding value.

```
Example:
Cassandra - 252.27
Preethi - 75
Vahe - 75
```

---

php Code:

```
<?php 

 error_reporting(0);

    mysql_connect("localhost","***","***");
    mysql_select_db("azracoma_***"); 

    $sql = "SELECT sum( gp ) FROM `mtdfix` WHERE name = 'VAHE KASSARDJIAN' ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die('Error query failed');
    $VAHE = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    $VAHE[0];

    $sql = "SELECT sum( gp ) FROM `mtdfix` WHERE name = 'PREETHI SELVARAJ' ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die('Error query failed');
    $PREETHI = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    $PREETHI[0];

    $sql = "SELECT sum( gp ) FROM `mtdfix` WHERE name = 'CASSANDRA PERERA' ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die('Error query failed');
    $CASSANDRA = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    $CASSANDRA[0];

$VAHEPOINTS = 0.653 * $VAHE[0];
$PREETHIPOINTS = 0.653 * $PREETHI[0];
$CASSANDRAPOINTS = 0.653 * $CASSANDRA[0];

?>
```

HTML with Php Vari's

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center"><?php echo $NAME; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $VARIABLEUNKNOWN; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><?php echo $NAME; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $VARIABLEUNKNOWN; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><?php echo $NAME; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $VARIABLEUNKNOWN; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

---

MySQL DB Table:

```
Name, Gp
CASSANDRA PERERA, 252.27
PREETHI SELVARAJ, 75
VAHE KASSARDJIAN, 75
```

I need to know how to correctly list variables into the TD's and have the name follow the correct `$VARIABLEUNKNOWN`
At the moment I can see the value on the DB when I `echo $VAHEPOINTS` so that's all working.

I'm really stuck and if anyone thinks editing is required please suggest.

Comment: Is `$AMOUNT` just the value in the `Gp` column?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. The $AMOUNT ideally will be:                     
TD1 = Highest $NAME_POINTS($CASSANDRAPOINTS) variable 
TD2 = Second Highest $NAME_POINTS($VAHEPOINTS) variable
TD3 = As above

Comment: I understand the order in which you want the amounts displayed. What I don't understand is where the value for `$AMOUNT` comes from.

Comment: $AMOUNT was put there as an example.
I'll change it to Variable UNKNOWN

Comment: But that still begs the question: what *is* it?

Comment: I don't know the syntax required to achieve what i need.
In saying this truly what it is, is the GP amount * 0.653 for the correct name of the answer.